# How to debug Unit Tests with Karma/Jasmine in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, karma-runner, visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to debug unit tests in Visual Studio Code, but so far it has been a mixed bag.

My setup:

**launch.json**

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
           {
              "name": "Debug tests",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "attach",
              "port": 9222,
              "sourceMaps": true,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
           }
   ]
}
```

**karma.config.js**

```
customLaunchers: {
   Chrome_with_debugging: {
     base: 'Chrome',
     flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222']
   }
}
```

This does seem to work in a way, if I launch the VS Code debugger it appears to attach (bottom bar turns orange). If I make a change, Karma kicks in and the debugger, too - but it invariably pauses in `zone.js` (this is an Angular project by the way) without me interfering in any way:

[image: Paused in zone.js]

If I hit 'Continue' it actually hits my breakpoint

[image]

and I can inspect some variables but not all of them,

[image: Some vars are displayed, some not]

For example, I can't see the value of `actual` passed into Jasmine's `expect` method.

So a) Why does the debugger always pause inside `zone.js` - the tested code is from a Redux reducer and is invoked outside of any Angular context, and b) What am I missing in regards to not being able to inspect local variables (which is a showstopper right now)?

Answer (score 22):

In karma.conf.js I updated added debug option in your version.

```
customLaunchers: {
   Chrome_with_debugging: {
     base: 'Chrome',
     flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
     debug: true
}}
```

**launch.json**
Add below snippet as launch configuration,

```
{
    "name": "Debug tests",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 9222,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

Then triggered the tests using below command,

`ng test --browsers Chrome_with_debugging`

Use Visual Studio Code debug option "Debug tests" to get attached to UT. With this I am able to debug unit tests using breakpoints in "Visual Studio Code + Debugger for Chrome extension".

Comment: Excellent - after struggling to get debugging in unit testing working as described in the Microsoft/vscode-recipes GitHub repo, this finally worked for me.

Comment: I get: Cannot load browser "Chrome_with_debugging": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin? I have the Debugger for Chrome installed.