# Debugging React Unit Tests (Karma/Jasmine)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, webstorm, karma-jasmine

Instead of console outputting variables to Chrome when running Karma/Jasmine spec files how can I set a breakpoint and then single step ?

I've setup WebStorm 2017 to run my Karma conf (with node), it runs my tests, in its Debug Mode, but never hits the breakpoints in my .spec files. I'm testing React / Reducers btw.

Is there a native way of doing this ?

Or can someone point me to a good link for debugging/single stepping UnitTest .spec files in WebStorm or Visual Studio Code ?

I looked at this but can't get it working 
[How to debug Unit Tests with Karma/Jasmine in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637891/how-to-debug-unit-tests-with-karma-jasmine-in-visual-studio-code?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting my question i came across this link

Hope it helps

http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html